# speech to text from wav file c#

Tags: c#, audio

I have some wav files in which integers are spoken. I need to detect these individual integers and convert to string. you can download mp3 file from:
[here](http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/noscript?k=6Lc_7NESAAAAAKNnHhdyT1E_FzMuFMUdn_CSfpcm&is_audio=true)

Using `Microsoft SpeechRecognitionEngine`, I can hardly detect an integer from any of the wav file.

This is SRE settings:

```
sre.SetInputToWaveFile("D:\\Speeches\\Best3.wav");
sre.BabbleTimeout = new TimeSpan(Int32.MaxValue);
sre.InitialSilenceTimeout = new TimeSpan(Int32.MaxValue);
sre.EndSilenceTimeout = new TimeSpan(100000000);
sre.EndSilenceTimeoutAmbiguous = new TimeSpan(100000000);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think some of your timeout values are extreme, but I was able to get a variety of `wav` files to parse with code like this:

```
using System;
using System.Speech.Recognition;

namespace SR
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var sre = new SpeechRecognitionEngine())
            {
                sre.SetInputToWaveFile(@"D:\test.wav");
                sre.LoadGrammar(new DictationGrammar());

                sre.BabbleTimeout = new TimeSpan(Int32.MaxValue);
                sre.InitialSilenceTimeout = new TimeSpan(Int32.MaxValue);
                sre.EndSilenceTimeout = new TimeSpan(100000000);
                sre.EndSilenceTimeoutAmbiguous = new TimeSpan(100000000);

                var result = sre.Recognize();
                Console.WriteLine(result.Text);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
}
```

You need to call `LoadGrammar()`.  There may be better option than `DictationGrammar`, but it worked for my samples.

You'll also want to check `result` for `null`, as it will be if the recognition fails.

Comment: You could load a custom grammar that only contains integers 0-9 or any range that would be included. Then only those numbers will be recognized and not Any non-integers if they exist. Grammars can be pretty tricky, but I did this for a custom grammar to open items in a list based on speaking the row number, so it can be done

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 can you provide a grammar as you mentioned, only for numbers ?